# React Native: When / how often should you update libraries?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, module, version, module-versions

In React Native apps, should you try to keep all libraries/modules on their latest versions? How do you approach this?

Answer (score 1):

As per say, it's always better to upgrade the libraries frequently and use those libraries which are popular. Suppose you use an old library which uses `componentWillMount` and that's deprecated. So it may cause some sideissues in your app which you want be able to trace.

But as like ruain change, you should always look for the modules before updating, like `react-navigation` almost the complete flow is different in v5 and v4 , so you need to change your app flow and also test the whole app again. Similiarly in `react-firebase` v5 and v6 is totally differnt.

TL,DR: Yes , you should update , but after updating check all the changes in modules and test your whole app again.

Hope it  helps. feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

I try to migrate after a certain time, as the most recent ones always come with great instability.

An example of this is the new version of:

```
react-navigation
```

version 5

is not dealing very well with the react-native-cli version, but is getting along very well with the expo

Comment: As in, do you always eventually upgrade each library? I agree about not upgrading right away, but I'm more wondering whether, for example, if a project is using the older version of `react-navigation` and everything's working fine and you don't need to add new features to the app, is there a reason to continue keeping all the modules up-to-date?

Comment: I do not see the need to update, since everything goes smoothly.
Only if it really starts to break